# Include auto increment value in stored CLOB

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I'm storing a json object as clob in a table, which has an auto increment ID field. I want to include the auto increment ID in clob while storing. Is there any way to do this, whithout updating the record again after inserting. (I use jdbc with h2 engine)

Comment: You mean the increment id value -  which is being stored in an ID column? And, this json in the clob will need this incremented field added to it?

Comment: Have you considered using an application generated auto increment ID for that purpose?

Comment: Another way to do this is to have two tables -  a main table with auto increment ID column. And, a secondary table with the clob (with json data) column. Inserting in two tables may need to be performed in a transaction. I think this may work too.

Comment: Yes. I want to store the value of the incremented ID column to the CLOB. I can't get an application generated ID (incremented) unless I read the last ID in the table right? So that will be 2 transactions. Having 2 tables will be an added complexity, and also 2 transactions. I'm looking for the most simple way to do this.

Comment: _I can't get an application generated ID (incremented) unless I read the last ID in the table right? _ Well, you can have an `application_d` table with one column and this tracks the ID numbers.

Comment: Yes but, that is 2 tables again. No advantage compared to running an update query after insertion to add the ID to the CLOB.

Comment: @imeshU - See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788290/include-auto-increment-value-in-stored-clob#comment92507062_52790853) to Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two solutions:

1. Use a sequence and retrieve the value, generate your clob content with the ID and then insert with id and clob
2. Use a trigger that modifies your clob

I have written two small examples on how to do this.

Personally I think that the first would be preferable in most situations, the solution with the trigger can be very brittle and tricky to do right. It can be especially tricky if the clob content is - for example - XML or JSON generated from an object model, where putting in placeholders like `##ID##` in my example is not always feasible or hard to do (eg if the field is typed as an integer).

## 1. Using a sequence

```
public class WithSequence {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:seqdb";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL)) {
            initDb(connection);
            int id = getNextId(connection);
            insertClobWithId(id, connection);
            outputTableContent(connection);
        }
    }

    // creates table and sequence
    private static void initDb(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement ddlStmt = connection.createStatement()) {
            ddlStmt.execute("create table clobwithid ("
                    + " id integer primary key,"
                    + " clobvalue clob"
                    + ")");
            ddlStmt.execute("create sequence seq_clobwithid");
        }
    }

    // obtain next id from sequence
    private static int getNextId(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select next value for seq_clobwithid")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getInt(1);
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError(" next value for should produce value");
            }
        }
    }

    // generate and insert clob
    private static void insertClobWithId(int id, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String clobValue = "Something with id=" + id + " and other stuff";
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "insert into clobwithid(id, clobvalue) values(?, ?)")) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, clobValue);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    private static void outputTableContent(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, clobvalue from clobwithid")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("%d : %s%n", rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## 2. Using a trigger

```
public class WithTrigger {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:seqdb";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL)) {
            initDb(connection);
            insertClob(connection);
            outputTableContent(connection);
        }
    }

    // create database and trigger
    private static void initDb(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement ddlStmt = connection.createStatement()) {
            ddlStmt.execute("create table clobwithid ("
                    + " id integer auto_increment primary key,"
                    + " clobvalue clob"
                    + ")");
            ddlStmt.execute("create trigger bi_clobwithid before insert on clobwithid for each row call \"example.ClobUpdateTrigger\"");
        }
    }

    // insert clob with a placeholder to be modified by the trigger
    private static void insertClob(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String clobValue = "Something with id=##ID## and other stuff";
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "insert into clobwithid(clobvalue) values(?)")) {
            pstmt.setString(1, clobValue);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    private static void outputTableContent(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, clobvalue from clobwithid")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("%d : %s%n", rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the trigger class is:

```
public class ClobUpdateTrigger extends TriggerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void fire(Connection connection, ResultSet oldRs, ResultSet newRs) throws SQLException {
        int generatedId = newRs.getInt(1);
        // We need to use reader to avoid internal casting problems
        String insertedClobValue = toString(newRs.getCharacterStream("clobvalue"));
        String updatedClobValue = insertedClobValue != null
                ? insertedClobValue.replace("##ID##", String.valueOf(generatedId))
                : null;
        newRs.updateString("clobvalue", updatedClobValue);
    }

    private static String toString(Reader reader) throws SQLException {
        try {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                sw.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return sw.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions, but the question strikes me as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238021) (or perhaps just a "'Why?' problem"). If the point is to associate the CLOB with the auto-increment ID then that is a natural consequence of inserting the (original) CLOB into the table. There's no real need to modify the CLOB itself since both the CLOB and the ID are "linked" by virtue of being in the same row of the database table. If at some point the CLOB needs to be updated to include the ID then that can happen when it is *extracted*, rather than when it is *inserted*.

Comment: @GordThompson This may indeed be an XY-problem. I just liked to experiment with this question as the starting point ;) That said, I can think of cases where a clob could contain the serialized presentation of the record including the id (eg maybe to speed up some rest API to avoid it having to build and serialize the same message on each request). In that case maybe the trigger from solution 2 should do all the work of creating the clob though (also useful for an update trigger to keep the clob up-to-date).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This answers the questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

**(1) Using a Sequence:**

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (my_id INT PRIMARY KEY, my_id_2 INT);
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (my_seq.nextval, my_seq.currval)
SELECT * FROM test1;
```

The output:

```
MY_ID   MY_ID_2 
1       1
```

Note the two columns have the same generated value.

**(1a) Alternate Application of Sequence:**

Run a SQL using a statement, with this script: "CALL NEXT VALUE FOR my_seq" to get the next sequence value.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("call next value for my_seq");
rs.next();
long value = rs.getLong(1); // NOTE: the return value is a long
```

Use this sequence value to insert into multiple columns of the target table.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, although solution 1a would be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. This provides a base to the solution